# locating a rotated image (90 deg increments) in Sikuli

Tags: sikuli

I have an image. Let's say it's this image:

[image: a golden cookie]

It doesn't have to be this image, but for my current purposes... It's (sadly for my sanity) this image.

I want to detect when this image is on screen... but not just this image, I want to detect all of the different 90 degree increment rotations.

What is the most appropriate (in the sense of code and *especially* of resource economy) way of doing this through the facilities available via Sikuli IDE (v 1.0.1, Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be available with current Sikuli features. You can find a similar question [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/119194), on Sikuli Launchpad.

You can use an external image processor like ImageMagic, to rotate your captured pictures and save them as samples that you can use in an `exists()` loop.